# Filter ReactiveList on background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have a collection of object which need filtering. The filter callback is time consuming so I need to run it on a background thread.
I create a derived Reactive list with CreateDerivedCollection(..)

```
_reactiveCollection = RawFileList.CreateDerivedCollection<string, string>(new Func<string, string>((s) => s),
                    new Func<string, bool>((s) => OnFilter(s)),null,RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler);
```

I used **RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler** to perform operations on a background thread but the filter callback is still called on the UI thread.

How to perform collection filtering on a background thread and notifiy collection change in UI Thread?

the reactive collection is used as ItemSource of an ItemsControl so change must be notified on UI Thread.

Comment: When you create the list the first filter isn't going to be scheduled it'll just run on whatever thread the list is created from, subsequent changes will be on the Taskpool though, resets are run on whatever thread they are called from. Since you want to prepare the entire list first before alerting the UI thread would it work to instead just swap out the list? Like prepare a new list on the background thread and then set it to some ImmutableList property? Good example of this here https://github.com/kentcb/WorkoutWotch/blob/master/Src/WorkoutWotch.ViewModels/ExerciseProgramsViewModel.cs

Comment: @ShaneNeuville Thank for your awnser.
In the end, I didn't use a Reactive Derived List. I just created my filtered list in a BackgroundWorker and assigned to my ItemSource in the RunWorkerCompleted callback.